# In order to prevent replay attacks, when should I accept and reject timestamps?

Tags: cryptography, timestamp, nonce

In order to prevent replay attacks, I'm implementing a mechanism where the client has to send to the server a nonce token, which is comprised of an UUID and a timestamp. They are both generated by the client.

However, I'm having concerns regarding the timestamp. I understand that for this to work, the clocks of the server and the clients must be in sync. I do not have control over the clients and, intuitively, it seems unrealistic to expect the server and clients' clocks to be fully in sync. As such, I expect that a client's clock might be a few seconds too early or too late.

Moreover, I expect a few seconds difference between the time the client has sent the nonce token and the time the server has received it. I expect the gap to be more important if the client's connection is poor.

Because of those concerns, I have decided to:

- Reject timestamps more than 2 minutes old;
- Reject timestamps set up more than 10 seconds into the future.

I would like the input of programmers who've dealt with timestamp validation. Do you see issues with the choices I've made regarding timestamp validation? What are the issues *you* have encountered?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any good reason for generating nonces on the client side, and you appear to have identified a very good reason for *not* doing so. I think you would be better off adhering to the procedure illustrated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

Comment: @r3mainer I see. Yes, it makes more sense to have the server generates the nonce. The only drawback I see is increased load on the server (but that should be very manageable), but nothing else. Do you see other drawbacks?

Comment: I imagine that different clients producing identical nonces (either accidentally or on purpose) would cause problems.